# Connect: No such Slot QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt, qobject, qtcore, qt-signals

I have inherited a class `MainTree` from `QTreeview`

**maintree.cpp file**

```
void  MainTree::LaunchTree()
{
//Tree launching
 connect(this, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint& )),this,SLOT(showCustomContextMenu(const QPoint&)));
}

void MainTree::showCustomContextMenu(const QPoint &pos)  
{
  //Add actions

}
```

But i get the following error

```
QObject::connect: No such slot QTreeView::showCustomContextMenu(const QPoint&)
```

I could not understand why, am i missing something ??

Definition of the class `MainTree`

```
class MainTree : public QTreeView
{

public:
    MainTree();
    MainTree(QWidget *parent = 0);

public slots:

private slots:
    void showCustomContextMenu(const QPoint& pos);

private:
     void launchTree();

 };
```

Comment: can you show the class definition of `MainTree`?

Comment: You forgot to add `Q_OBJECT` macro in the beginning of your class declaration.

Comment: I tried to do that before as well. But when i add the macro Q_OBJECTm i get the following error.

Q_OBJECT throwing 'undefined reference to vtable' error

Comment: @user3387634 Do not forget to run `qmake` again, before building your project.

Comment: this error usually means that build cache is corrupted. Clean project an build it again.

Comment: @vahancho: Thank you. I did not run 'qmake' before, which was the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `Q_OBJECT` macro out, so try this:

```
class MainTree : public QTreeView
{
Q_OBJECT
// ^^^^^
public:
    MainTree();
    MainTree(QWidget *parent = 0);

public slots:

private slots:
    void showCustomContextMenu(const QPoint& pos);

private:
     void launchTree();

 };
```

Do not forget to re-run qmake after this to regenerate the moc files properly. Make sure you have the moc include at the end of your source code, or you handle the moc generation without that.

Also, note that if you used Qt 5.2 or later with C++11 support, you would get a static assertion about the missing Q_OBJECT macro, so you would not get runtime issues anymore. I suggest to follow that if you can.

Answer (score -3):

When referring to slot and signals you have to omnit all decoration: `const` `&` and so on (only star can remain).

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)), 
        this, SLOT(showCustomContextMenu(QPoint)))
```

Also you forgot about `Q_OBJECT` macro.

Comment: No, "foo(const X&)" is valid and works. "foo(X)” and “foo(const X&)” are equivalent after the signature normalization done by the connect(). "foo(X)” is to be preferred because it’s more concise (and slightly faster, as no normalization is needed), but the behavior is the same.

Comment: Maybe it works by Qt documentation says it is recommended to omit this.

Comment: I am afraid Frank is right, or at least I agree with him about it. He wrote that Q_OBJECT did not help on its own either, so I suggest to delete this answer now that it got so many downvotes, and there are better answer. Of course, you can still keep around if you wish, it is just my personal opinion.