# Signal to it's own instance doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt5, signals-slots, qpushbutton

I connected the clicked(bool) event from QPushButton to a private slot mySlot() of my own Widget. But the slot is never called (I placed a breakpoint in mySlot()). I'm using c++ and Qt5.
I wrote a minimal version of my code:

MyLayout.h

```
class MyLayout : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyLayout(QWidget* parent = NULL);
private:
    QPushButton *next;
private slots:
    void mySlot();
}
```

MyLayout.cpp

```
MyLayout::MyLayout(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    next = new QPushButton("Next Step");
    QObject::connect(next, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(mySlot()));
}
void MyLayout::mySlot() { /* do something */ }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You are missing a `Q_OBJECT` macro for moc to generate your signal / slot helpers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221798/connect-no-such-slot-qtreeview

Comment: I just added the 'QWidget' parameter for my constructor. But When I add the 'Q_OBJECT' macro I get a linker error.

Comment: That means either moc is not run or the generated moc source is not part of your project.

Comment: OK! Now my code looks like the code above. It can be build and run. But the Next button is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You created a parentless button and never showed it. Start by giving it parent (`this`), so it gets shown together with your widget:

```
next = new QPushButton("Next Step", this);
```

Then learn how to use [layouts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).